# Transaction like Http Post, Possible?

Tags: rest, api, post, rollback

Hi i am for the time being building a REST Api and i am wondering about an idea i have for secure data posting.

I have data that i have to delegate to two different endpoints in the same Post and i am wondering if there is any way to "test-post" to the endpoints before posting for real solving the problematic scenarion in which one of the systems that i'm sending to would be down for a moment.

That is if one of the systems would be down i could return a failed request message instead.

For extra explanation of my thought:

- User posts data objet to my api via endpoint.
- I process data and later try to send processed data to two different systems via their endpoints in same process/method.
- IF systems ok then data is sent, and i return a OK.
- Else One of systems not ok i roll back (that is not sending processed data to either one of them), and return for example 500 Internal server error.

It is critical that when i send the data it has to be sent to both systems in same process, or none of them in same process if one system is down.

Hope i got you guys to understand what i am after.

Comment: interservice transactions is a difficult problem. Good luck, you're gonna need it :)

Comment: Noo, Don't say that! Thanks for the luck Though! :P